# jQuery datatables row click after data loaded by fnReloadAjax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I using fnReloadAjax to reload every 1 second a data table. 
Now I need use function on click row:

```
 $(".table td").click( function( e ) {
            alert('a');
        });
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: you need row then use tr

Answer (score 0):

Try using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(".table").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    alert('a');
});
```